# Log all users out of all locations after 24 hours

Tags: users, user-meta, user-access

Good day, experts. Please I need the code that can help me log all logged in users on my WordPress website out of all locations after a particular time.

This is what I have so far:

```
add_action('wp_login','user_update_login'); 

// function fires when a user logs in 
function user_update_login($login) { 
    global $user_ID; 
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($login); 
    // save the current time when the user logged in 
    update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() ); 
}

function check_time_limit() { 
    // populate the user objects
    global $user_ID;
    get_currentuserinfo(); 
    // ...
}
```

Thank you in anticipation of support.

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this?

Comment: function user_update_login($login) {
    // function fires when a user logs in

    global $user_ID;
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($login);

    // save the current time when the user logged in
    update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
}
add_action('wp_login','user_update_login');

function check_time_limit() {
    // populate the user objects
    get_currentuserinfo();
    global $user_ID;

Comment: Good day @user2969052! You are more likely to get an "expert" advice here on WPSE if your question includes what you have tried and researched yourself. "I need the code" is actually a phrase that drives experts *away* from this site...

Comment: @Michal Mau, Noted. I will use an appropriate phrase next time. I have tried but to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for understanding and sharing your code - I took the liberty to move it from the comment to the question. I also removed my downvote ,) Welcome to WPSE!

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways to accomplish what you want. I won't give you any use-ready solution but just an idea.

**First idea**
You could set up cron job to replace authentication keys in wp-config.php, you can get them over here https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
This way you will force all of the users to log in again.

**Second idea**
Create a new function to add some user date meta on successful login. On every page request, hook a new function to check if the meta value is greater than 24 hours, if it is, then logout specific user.

Comment: Natan Zasepa, thank you. I will appreciate if you help me further. I am new to WordPress. But working hard to better my best.

Comment: +1 for the first idea. Very simple but creative! You could also (potentially) run wp-cli's config generation command with the cron which might save some coding

Comment: @Tim Malone thank you. I wish I could do all these. I am here for support.Thanks

Comment: @user2969052 None of us are going to spoon feed you an answer. We're here in our spare time. You have several concepts to start googling for now.